# Python Beautifulsoup find special tag text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am struggling to find and turn the text in date into a system date and take this as variable to use somewhere else. I am looking for the date behind 'title' in tag `<span>`.

I tried couple of ways but not really come up with a straightforward solution. At last I used

```
modif_time = soup.find(text=re.compile('title'))
```

Here is the HTML code, where the information are.

```html
 <a class="browser-fle yjax-lik" href="/mendonhall/mendonhall_adm/files/e0e854aaf54cb711f7335c8d8ecac9766cd175e3/tak/P0328_dummy.docx">P0328_dummy.docx</a>
     </td>
     <td>
         20.7 KiB
     </td>
     <td>
          application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
     </td>
     <td>
             <div class="tool" title="tak directory">
              <pre>r28ee854af54c</pre>
             </div>
     </td>
     <td>
             <span class="tool" title="Fri, 19 Dec 2014 09:38:49">
            12 minutes and 48 seconds ago</span>
     </td>
     <td>
             <span title="id">
            xn06611 (Jeff Mendonhall)
            </span>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You are looking for *text between tags*, not for a `span` element with a `title` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
soup.find("span" title=True, class_='tool')
```

to get the value of the `span` tag's `title` attribute. `title=True` restricts the result to tags with the `title` attribute, and `class_='tool'` further restricts the result to those tags where the `class` attribute has the value `'tool'` (the underscore in `class_` avoids a clash with the Python reserved word).

You can convert this to a datetime object with

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime(soup.find("span" title=True, class_='tool')["title"], "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 1):

[`soup.find_all('span')`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) finds all the span tags in the HTML. You can [further filter](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments) the result by specifying a keyword argument.

```
import email.utils as EU    
soup.find_all('span', title=EU.parsedate)
```

finds all the span tags that have a title *attribute* for which [`EU.parsedate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate)
returns a Truish value.

```
In [112]: EU.parsedate('Fri, 19 Dec 2014 09:38:49')
Out[112]: (2014, 12, 19, 9, 38, 49, 0, 1, -1)
```

When EU.parsedate can not parse the title it returns None (a Falsish value).

Thus, `soup.find_all('span', title=EU.parsedate)` finds only those span tags whose title attribute looks like a date.

You can then convert the time tuple returned by EU.parsedate to a [datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) using `datetime.datetime(*timetuple[:6])`.

---

```
import bs4 as bs
import datetime as DT
import email.utils as EU    

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(open('data'))
spans = soup.find_all('span', title=EU.parsedate)

for span in spans:
    print(span.attrs['title'])
    # Fri, 19 Dec 2014 09:38:49

    timetuple = EU.parsedate(span.attrs['title'])
    date = DT.datetime(*timetuple[:6])
    print(date)
    # 2014-12-19 09:38:49
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

...

span = soup.find('span')
title = span['title']
print datetime.strptime(title, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
2014-12-19 09:38:49
```

Comment: you can at least tell `find()` to look for a `title` attribute with `soup.find('span', title=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

You will find below how to get all the span elements and keep only those with a date as "title".

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get(url).content   # url you're interested in 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
def is_date(x):
    try:
        time.strptime(x, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S") # Try to transform string into
        return True                               # a datetime object
    except:
        return False
print is_date("Fri, 19 Dec 2014 09:38:49") # it prints True 

res = [s for s in soup.findAll('span', title=True) if is_date(s['title'])]
print res
```

Here what it prints :

```
[<span class="tool" title="Fri, 19 Dec 2014 09:38:49">
           12 minutes and 48 seconds ago</span>]
```

Comment: you can at least tell `find_all()` to look for `title` attributes with `soup.find_all('span', title=True)`.